Study the sign of $\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha} \delta^*(\breve{\alpha}(y), y)$
I am currently reading Lemma 4.1 in [1], which considers a function $\delta^*(\alpha, y)$ with the properties
$$\lim_{\alpha \to 1^+} \delta^*(\alpha, y) = +\infty, \quad \lim_{\alpha \to +\infty} \delta^*(\alpha, y) = +\infty, \quad \lim_{\alpha \to 1^+} \frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha} \delta^*(\alpha, y) = -\infty, \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{\alpha \to +\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha} \delta^*(\alpha, y) = 1 \tag{1}$$
Given these conditions, it is stated that there exists a point $\breve{\alpha}(y) \in (1, +\infty)$ such that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha} \delta^*(\breve{\alpha}(y), y) = 0,\tag{2}$$
and further, that there exists some $\alpha > \breve{\alpha}(y)$ where
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha} \delta^*(\breve{\alpha}(y), y) > 0\tag{3}$$
I found (3) a little bit unclear. It seems more accurate to specify that there exists some $\alpha > \breve{\alpha}(y)$ such that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha} \delta^*(\alpha, y) > 0\tag{4}$$
Would it be more correct to express it this way? In addition, given that $\alpha > 1$, can we say that there is $\alpha \in (1, \breve{\alpha}(y))$ such that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha} \delta^*(\alpha, y) < 0 ?\tag{5}$$
[1] Ted Theodosopoulos, A reversion of the Chernoff bound, 2005.


says that the function will have a local minium.  3) says that after hitting the minimum it will at some time have to increase.


Those statements are actually poorly written. It should be $\dfrac{\partial\delta^*}{\partial\alpha}$ evaluated at $(\check\alpha(y),y)$ in both cases.

@user317176 thank you for the comment. But how can we derive (2) and (3) from (1)? Also, in (3) I am confused a little about the condition $\alpha > \breve{a}(y)$ and the arguments of $\delta^$ in (3). Should we write more correctly that there exists some $\alpha > \breve{\alpha}(y)$ where $\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha} \delta^(\alpha, y) > 0$

@TedShifrin thank you for the comment. Can you please provide an improved version of (2), (3), and how are derived from (1)?

You fix $y$ in these statements, so it's just single-variable calculus. If you have a function of $\alpha$ which tends to $\infty$ as $\alpha\to 1^+$ and $\to\infty$, then the function has a global minimum on the interval $(1,\infty)$. And you are correct in your editing of (3). I should have caught that, too. Again, at some (not necessarily every) point past the global minimum, the function must be increasing, since the function goes to $\infty$ eventually. (I would comment that you should be very critical when reading this paper, as it seems the author has not been too careful.)

Thank you for the explanation @TedShifrin. I am a little confused on the notation $\alpha > \breve{\alpha}(y)$ as $\alpha$ is the variable on which we compute the derivative. I would have expected to use some notation other than $\alpha$ on defining $\alpha > \breve{\alpha}(y)$. Am I wrong on that? Can we write that in better way?

No, that is precisely correct. $\alpha$ is in fact the independent variable here, and for various values $>\check\alpha(y)$ the derivative will be positive.

Thank you for the comment. Upon closer inspection, I believe I now understand that if $\breve{\alpha}(y)$ satisfies the condition $\alpha > \breve{\alpha}(y)$, then it seems valid to rewrite (3) by directly substituting $\breve{\alpha}(y)$ into the derivative. Does this reasoning hold?

Don't we need some kind of continuity assumptions about $\delta^*$? Otherwise it's possible to build piecewise functions that satisfy all of the conditions, but for which (2) does not hold.

@JohnBarber thank you for the comment. By looking the paper, $\delta^*$ is continuous wrt $\alpha$.

Is its derivative with respect to $\alpha$ also continuous?

@JohnBarber $\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha} \delta^{*}(\alpha, y)$ is continuous wrt $\alpha$.
